# Using "where" clauses to produce optional types in Swift arithmetic

Tags: ios, swift, uiscrollview, where-clause

I would like to trigger conditional logic based around certain UI relationships during user interaction (in this case, I want to call a method when a user scrolls to a certain point in a `UIScrollView`). I would expect the following line of code to do this legally, since it is quite expressive:

```
func scrollViewDidScroll(scrollView: UIScrollView) {
    guard let overlap = scrollView.contentOffset.y - 220 where overlap > 0 else {
        return
    }

    reactToScrollOverlap(of: overlap)
}
```

However, I get the error that the `guard let` requires an optional type. That's reasonable, but I expected in this case that the `where` clause would naturally introduce an optional, since if the arithmetic works out wrong then there is no matching value of `overlap`.

Is there a way to use `guard let` (or, alternatively, `if let`) such that included `where` clauses stipulate conditions on the outcomes of arithmetic between Int, CGFloat, or other primitive/primitive-like types?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are doing 3 things in one expression - declaring a variable (constant), assigning it and checking its value.

Declaring a variable in expressions is usually frowned upon, Swift does not really enable it. With one exception - unwrapping of optionals. You are not unwrapping an optional so just split the expression correctly into a declaration and a comparison:

```
let overlap = contentOffset.y - 220

guard overlap > 0 else {
    return
}
```

Another option is to use the `case let` pattern. I am not a big fan of it but it's probably what you want:

```
guard case let overlap = contentOffset.y - 220 where overlap > 0 else {
    return
}

print("overlap:", overlap)
```

Comment: i suppose this is the most expressive alternative, so I'll mark this as the answer until further notice (:

Comment: on second thought, I marked the other answer as correct because although you're right and I should probably do this instead, the workaround provided by JAL does use where clauses as indicated in the title.

Comment: @Quintana Try my second solution

Comment: Excellent suggestion. Def closest fit. You're right, it's not pretty. Though I used a similar pattern I think in an enumerating `for` loop somewhere. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

`guard` and `if let` statements are normally only used to unwrap optionals.  I'm not really thrilled with this solution, but you could cast `scrollView.contentOffset.y` as an `Optional<CGFloat>` to get the behavior you want:

```
guard let overlap = scrollView.contentOffset.y - 220 as CGFloat? where overlap > 0 else {
    return
}
```

Comment: This is a good workaround that I think gets to what I was hoping is possible. It's not thrilling, as you say, however -- wouldn't want to check it in. But I wish I could mark multiple correct answers. Thanks for pointing it out.

Answer (score 3):

```
guard let value = someOptionalValue {
}

if let value = someOptionalValue {
}
```

These are the way how you bind an optionals to a variable. If you are using `guard let` or `if let` you are using to get a value from optional types only.

and where clause will be triggered only when all the optionals have a value that precedes the where clause.

I think what you want to do is something like this:

```
let delta = scrollView.contentOffset.y - 220

if delta > 0 {

} else {

}
```

I would prefer clarity over brevity.

**Edit:**

Here is a better way to do it I think:

```
let yOffset        = scrollView.contentOffset.y
let newOffset:Int? = yOffset > 220 ? yOffset : nil
```

Comment: Makes sense. It's still not quite expressing what I would like -- since I'm only concerned with the offset wherein it is greater than 220, I would prefer to have a `nil` value rather than an "invalid" one; in the sense that "no delta could be created". however this does work, thanks.